# How do I make transparent background in text fields?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Say, i have a text field with some text in it, and i want to make it have a backgruond with alpha value (as in partially transparent, not sure how to make it sound good ^^). This text field reacts to mouse events, such as clicks and rolls out/over, and each event changes the background color.

I've done some digging and ran across `flash.text.TextField.backgroundColor` and `flash.text.TextField.background` properties of text fields. They're cool, but not enough to solve the problem. And obviously, if I change the text field's alpha value, the text will also become transparent.

I know I can create a movieclip below the text field and alter its properties to acheive my goal, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TLFTextField you have backgroundAlpha that you can use.

You can also try including the alpha in your color value, like 0x99FF0066, notice the 99, a good read on the subject can be found here:

http://myflex.wordpress.com/2007/09/07/about-hex-color-codes-in-flex-as3/